# meteor change merged stylesheet position

Tags: meteor

On my meteor project, I embed bootstrap CDN on the header. But due to the merged stylesheet is embedded right after the `<head>` tag, some of my styles are overwritten by the bootstrap. Here is the rough HTML looks like on browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="__meteor-css__" href="/merged-stylesheets.css?hash=e4358d3b8494bc13eda6b965c33b5902cd562a07">
  <meta ..>
  <title>...</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

How can I setup the merged stylesheet to be embedded after the CDN or right before `</head>` closing tag?

Answer (score 0):

That's currently a Meteor caveat, discussions are on-going here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor-feature-requests/issues/24

The possibility to change it will probably come in a future release